# What can I do to get my secret backstories question reopened?

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions

I've recently asked my first question: [Should players know each others' secret backstories?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/115485/should-players-know-each-others-secret-backstories)
It was put on hold as being primarily opinion based. I do understand that there might be no absolute answer to this. Still, I'm hoping for expert opinion that is helpful in forming a decision in such a question.

What information (about my players, about my world, the campaign, our agreed-upon meta rules, etc.) do I have to add to the question in order to make it less opinion-based?

Answer (score 8):

In cases like this sometimes a simple rewording is effective.  “Should I” is asking for opinions and will draw unhelpful yes or no answers.  “What are the pros and cons of”, on the other hand, draws expertise and gives you the information you need to draw your own conclusions.  Your question is good and pro/conny on the whole, but the “should I” is a magnet for drive-by opinion boyz.